# Write tcpdump output in a text file into a single line

Tags: bash, grep, tcpdump

I want to concatenate all lines in text output into one line.
With the following command I can monitor DHCP traffic:

`tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 1500 '((udp port 67) and (udp[247:4] = 0x63350103))' | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname'`

For every new connection I see 3 results ( IP, MAC, Hostname ) every one of them on a new line.

That's possible to write this three every results but into only one line and write on a file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` to remove newlines with -d. Running on my machine and using en0 instead of eth0, I see this on one line:

```sh
$ tcpdump -lni en0 -vvv -s 1500 '((udp port 67) and (udp[247:4] = 0x63350103))' | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname' | tr -d '\n' > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
        Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7      Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 172.31.99.198     Hostname Option 12, length 3: "mbp"
```

`>` Will overwrite a file with contents of stdin.
Check out tr's [manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html).

Comment: if I put "tr -d '\n'" didn't see results.

Comment: If you use `tr -d '\n' > output.txt`, you will not see results on your cli because it's being redirected to `output.txt`.